# Resolver route me to page 404 before reach the exact url

Tags: angular, resolver

When I request with url 'architecture/departements/3' everything works fine, method getListDepartementis called. But it route me first to 404 not found  and then it route me to the exact url

```
    navigateToDepartement() {
    this.router.navigate(['/reload']).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['/architecture/departements/' + this.idBranche]);
    })
  }
```

Here's the resolver:

```
      export class DepartmentResolveService implements Resolve<any[]>{
     constructor(public brancheService: BrancheService) { }
     resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.brancheService.getListDepartement(route.params['id'])
  }
```

My routing code:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
     {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: BranchesComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'departements/:id',
        component: DepartmentListComponent,
        resolve: { departement: DepartmentResolveService },
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to prevent passing to 404 before reaching the URL.

Comment: Sounds like you are sending a request for `architecture/departements/3` to the server, which is not configured to return `index.html` for all frontend routes.

Comment: No,just I use it to route me to the next page when i pass to the resolver i call the api with id thats all and the response will be json format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really understand why you are calling 'reload' page you should remove it, here is what you should do:

```
navigateToDepartement() {
      this.router.navigate(['/architecture/departements/' + this.idBranche]);
  }
```

There is no need to call reload page, i think it should works

Comment: my previous code is same as this and same problem appear but i try some solutions wich it use reload

Comment: I see could you try to achieve this reload page manually, like this **localhost:4200/reload**  if it gives you 404 so you should add it properly in routing file

Comment: i take it off from my code and i use the previous one like you say it's a wrong way